# Существует ли аналог imagettfbbox() в ImageMagick?

Tags: php, gd, imagemagick

Приветствую. Ищу аналог функции php/GD [`imagettfbbox()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) в php/ImageMagick, так как во всём приложении используется php/ImageMagick и ради одной функции ставить GD как-то не очень правильно выглядит. Заранее спасибо.